# Number sequence for custom table in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, number-sequence

I have a custom utility which uses a custom table in AX 2012 AOT, I want to have an identity field for my table and someone tell me I can use number sequences for this, and can map a number sequence to my table so it can get a new unique id at the time of row insert, when I try to generate number sequence it asks me AREA and module information, since i want this for my custom table and utility which is working outside the dynamics ax 2012 using .net business connector, I am unable to figure out what to input the wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably seen the method of using NumberSeqModule enum and adding a custom module enum value to it. Then you would normally create a class that extends the NumberSeqApplicationModule class and then load the numbersequences linked to the data types using number sequence references.

Though this is the 'best practice way', it is a bit of overkill for what you would want to do now. So here is what you can do:

You could just overwrite the insert method of the table you are using. And the you could use the  newGetNumFromCode constructor on the NumberSeq class.

```
public static NumberSeq newGetNumFromCode(
    NumberSequenceCode  _numberSequenceCode,
    NumberSeqScope      _scope = NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDefaultScope(),
    boolean             _makeDecisionLater           = false,
    boolean             _dontThrowOnMissingRefSetUp  = false,
    SysLastValue        _nextNumSeq = null,
    boolean             _fillNextNumSeq = false)
{
    return NumberSeq::newGetNumFromId(
            NumberSequenceTable::findByNaturalKey(_numberSequenceCode, _scope.getId()).RecId,
            _makeDecisionLater,
            _dontThrowOnMissingRefSetUp,
            _nextNumSeq,
            _fillNextNumSeq);
}
```

So now to use this, you just have to create a new numbersequence within Dynamics Ax (Organization administration | Number Sequences | Number Sequences) and remember the number sequence code.

Then on the insert method of your table you can do the following: (the example is taken from the contact person table)

```
if (!this.ContactPersonId)
{
    this.ContactPersonId = NumberSeq::newGetNum(CompanyInfo::numRefContactPersonId()).num();
}
```

That should make sure that when a record is inserted, you will also fill the ID.

Comment: thanks Kenny, I created a number sequence and override my insert method and used newGetNumFromCode method, I got duplicate numbers, then someone told me that I have to use continous number sequence and wrap the code in a transaction TTSBegin and TTSEnd. It worked.

Comment: @Kenny Saelen: you used NumberSeq::newGetNum() in this example. I'm creating NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(), but it (at times, not always) throw an exception that "Number sequence does not exist". Any idea why is this so? I have generated number sequence using "new number sequence" in organization administration and not through code (using EDT stuff, loadModule() methods and all) or generate sequence wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This is how u you number sequence in normal way

```
custTable.xyz = NumberSeq::newGetNum(CompanyInfo::numrefContactId()).num();
```

Comment: That is indeed the answer above :)